# Test plain javascript file returning different objects

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, es6-modules, jasmine2.0

Is it possible to test the code below with Jasmine testing tool or any other npm module like [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) or similar?

```
const AuthValidatorDumb = require('./src/AuthValidatorDumb');
const AuthValidator = require('./src/AuthValidator');
const config = require('../config');

let instance;

if (!instance) {
  if (config.get('auth.enabled')) {
    instance = AuthValidator;
  } else {
    instance = AuthValidatorDumb;
  }
}

module.exports = instance;
```

Comment: Could you please try not to write such comments to people? If you have anything helpful to say, please do it

Answer (score 0):

I've got a variant for testing the code above.Suppose you have:

1) The code for index.js in the question above.

2) **AuthValidator.js**:

```
class AuthValidator {}
module.exports = AuthValidator;
```

3) **AuthValidatorDumb.js**:

```
class AuthValidatorDumb {}
module.exports = AuthValidatorDumb;
```

Here is **test/index.spec.js**:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const AuthValidator = require('../src/AuthValidator');
const AuthValidatorDumb = require('../src/AuthValidatorDumb');

describe('auth index', () => {
  it('should return AuthValidator', () => {
    const configMock = { get: () => 'sth' };
    const Instance = proxyquire('../index', {
      '../config': configMock,
    });
    expect(new Instance() instanceof AuthValidator).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return AuthValidatorDumb', () => {
    const configMock = { get: () => undefined };
    const Instance = proxyquire('../index', {
      '../config': configMock,
    });
    expect(new Instance() instanceof AuthValidatorDumb).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```